# Is there a way to have PHP output an array of all characters available?

Tags: php, arrays, character

Is there any way to have PHP return an array of all available characters?

Comment: What do you mean by "all available characters"?

Comment: If you mean all Unicode characters that array will be biiiiiiiiiiiig.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate an array that contains a list of all **ASCII** characters by using [range](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) and [chr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) functions:

```
// Create an array containing a range of ASCII elements. 
$bytes =  range (0 , 255);
$all_chars = array_map('chr', $bytes);
```

Comment: wouldnt that always put only the standard 255 characters in the array ? what if there are extra ??

Comment: @Pheonix I emphasized the word "ASCII", there might always be extra characters since character is a symbolic concept.

Comment: By saying ASCII I mean extended ASCII (which is 8-bit), not the original 7-bit definition. Everybody already knows that.

Answer (score 0):

If *all available characters* means unicode characters then the answer is no.  The unicode standard has a [roadmap](http://www.unicode.org/roadmaps/) for the gradual adaption of new characters.  PHP can verify the validity of some byte sequences (e.g. UTF-8 streams) but does not aggressively check that those sequences are currently part of the standard; e.g. there are gaps in the unicode codepoints that are not currently valid, but might become so, and which UTF-8 sequences represent.

Answer (score 0):

I Used this code ::

```
$array = array();
$x = 0;

while(!in_array(chr($x), $array)){
    $array[] = chr($x);
    $x++;
}

print_r($array);
```